# Passing Angular Expression to a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, I was trying a code with `ng-repeat` but got stuck because I need to pass the angular expression to a function but it is not working below is my code:

HTML code

```
     <div ng-controller="Profile as pro">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li ng-repeat="tabs in tabArray" 
           ng-class="{active: pro.tab==1}" 
           ng-click=" pro.setTab({{tabs.value}})">
         <a href="">{{tabs.name}}</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     <div>
```

Controller code

```
controller.controller('Profile', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.tabArray = [
            {name:"Profile","value":1},
            {name:"Education","value":2},
            {name:"Work","value":3},
            {name:"About","value":4}
        ];
        this.tab=1;
        this.setTab = function(tabSelected){
            this.tab=tabSelected;
        };
     }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only proble in your code is in following line:

```
ng-click=" pro.setTab({{tabs.value}})" // don't use {{ and }} thing here, it is not needed
```

Following code is fixed version:

```
ng-click="pro.setTab(tabs.value)" // only {{ and }} are removed and it works well
```

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 1):

**Use** `ng-click ="pro.setTab(tabs.value)"`

Answer (score 0):

There were some mistakes in your existing code ->

1. > Since you are making use of **ControllerAs** syntax, you should refer with the `variable` used for the `controller`, with all the variables referenced in the view.

Here, in the `ng-repeat` of your model refer by `pro.tabArray`.

2. > There is no need to pass the parameters in **AngularExpressions**, at the time of function/method call.

So, make use of `ng-click="pro.setTab(tabs.value)"`, without the expressions.

**HTML Code:**

```
<li ng-repeat="tabs in pro.tabArray" ng-class="{'active': pro.tab==1}" ng-click="pro.setTab(tabs.value)"><a href="">{{tabs.name}}</a></li>
```

3. > In your `JS` too, you have referred some varibales with `$scope` and some with `this`. Be consistent with your code and do not mix it.

**JS Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Profile', function ($scope) {
    this.tabArray = [
              { name: "Profile", "value": 1 },
              { name: "Education", "value": 2 },
              { name: "Work", "value": 3 },
              { name: "About", "value": 4 }
    ];
    this.tab = 1;
    this.setTab = function (tabSelected) {
        this.tab = tabSelected;
    };
    $scope = this;
});
```